# how to retrieve values from JSON object and authenticate using google-plus:0.1 plugin

Tags: json, grails

I am using google-plus:0.1 plugin in a Grails Application to enable login using Google+ ,I have successfully logged in and I am getting JSON object back.

Inside plugin there is a code where they are turning JSON string to JSON object and returning back to me.
This is the code inside a plugin:-

```
public Person getCurrentUserProfile() {
    Person person
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=${this.accessToken}")
        def jsonString = JSON.parse(url?.text)
        println "URL : " + url.toString()
        println "JSON : " + jsonString

        person = Person.parseJSONForPerson(jsonString)
    } catch (GooglePlusException e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return person
}
```

From here I am getting JSON object back
Json string printed in console is:-

```
URL : https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=ya29.lgFPSagK5lQ8l19hWuxra8AxsXzZjxlbCetP-aWpUHbq2_djrdvj-3XMFMEgl9r4WfaiLvo7Q3RfJQ
JSON : [etag:"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/eUT2aym4R39YBu_ra8ZlhztXJ6w", organizations:[[startDate:1995, title:Science, primary:false, name:St.Joseph's Convent, endDate:2008, type:school]], image:[isDefault:false, url:https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-kuh1_bl_8is/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADA/ZZfY8ob2QrQ/photo.jpg?sz=50], isPlusUser:true, emails:[[value:kartiki.sahu@crowdera.co, type:account]], kind:plus#person, url:https://plus.google.com/102332421579091283598, id:102332421579091283598, verified:false, name:[familyName:Sahu, givenName:Kartiki], domain:crowdera.co, circledByCount:9, gender:female, displayName:Kartiki Sahu, objectType:person]
```

I am unable to fetch emails from the object which I am getting.

I tried fetching familyName as 
person.name.familyName I got it's value, 
but for givenName it is showing null and for emails and organisation it is showiing empty list like [].

My code :-

```
def code = request.getParameter("code")
    String accessToken = accessTokenService.generateAccessToken(code)
    googlePlusService.accessToken = accessToken
    def person = googlePlusService.getCurrentUserProfile()
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value like this .

```
      String str="""{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/eUT2aym4R39YBu_ra8ZlhztXJ6w\\"",
 "gender": "female",
 "emails": [
  {
   "value": "kartiki.sahu@crowdera.co",
   "type": "account"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "102332421579091283598",
 "displayName": "Kartiki Sahu",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Sahu",
  "givenName": "Kartiki"
 },
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/102332421579091283598",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-kuh1_bl_8is/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADA/ZZfY8ob2QrQ/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 },
 "organizations": [
  {
   "name": "St.Joseph's Convent",
   "title": "Science",
   "type": "school",
   "startDate": "1995",
   "endDate": "2008",
   "primary": false
  }
 ],
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "circledByCount": 9,
 "verified": false,
 "domain": "crowdera.co"
}
"""
        def jsonString  = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str)
        render jsonString.emails.value
    }
```

I am getting output as a following list .

```
['kartiki.sahu@crowdera.co']
```

Comment: I tried using person.emails.value but still I am unable to get values.  I am getting list as [ ] i.e. empty list.

Comment: @KartikiSahu , You are showing json is invalid json .I tried using https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=${this.accessToken} output and i am able to get email. Please post correct json response .

Comment: This isn't my code . It's the code I got in plugin. I used def code = request.getParameter("code")
  String accessToken = accessTokenService.generateAccessToken(code)
  googlePlusService.accessToken = accessToken
  def person = googlePlusService.getCurrentUserProfile()

Comment: I have added the url and json response I got.Please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: @KartikiSahu See my updated answer , I was receiving this response and i got email list .

Comment: Thanks I have directly used the pluggin code to my controller  and I got the ans.

Comment: Hey praveen I again need your help, I want to authenticate user and logged in user to my grails application.It is using spring security service to log in directly.I am not able to logged in.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def code = request.getParameter("code")
    String accessToken = accessTokenService.generateAccessToken(code)
    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?                                                                                                                    
    access_token=${accessToken}")
    def jsonString = JSON.parse(url?.text)
    println "URL : " + url.toString()
    println "JSON : " + jsonString
    println "emails  "+jsonString.emails.value[0]
    println "name  "+jsonString.name.givenName + " " + 
    jsonString.name.familyName
```